# Check if two attributes exist for an element

Tags: javascript, jquery

The first two if statements work, but when it gets to checking if the select option has both attributes it won't display the proper message. How can this be altered to allow for checking both attributes?

```
        $("select option").each(function () {
            if ($(this).attr('data-disabled')) {
                $(this).append('\'s account is disabled');
            } else if ($(this).attr('data-locked')) {
                $(this).append('\'s account is locked out');
            } else if ($(this).attr('data-disabled') && $(this).attr('data-locked')) {
                $(this).append('\'s account is disabled & locked');
            };
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first `if` hits, which means your `else`s don't run. Just move your third `if` to be first.

Answer (score 0):

Just move your last if to be the first like that:

```
$("select option").each(function () {
    if ($(this).attr('data-disabled') && $(this).attr('data-locked')) {
        $(this).append('\'s account is disabled & locked');
    } else if ($(this).attr('data-disabled')) {
        $(this).append('\'s account is disabled');
    } else if ($(this).attr('data-locked')) {
        $(this).append('\'s account is locked out');
    } 
});
```